# New to React, struggling to understand this bug: conditional message is not always displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

probably a very noob problem that is keeping me busy since 3 days. I am building the classic memory card (One Piece Themed), I am trying to add a "Winning message" supposedly shown whenever all the cards have been matched. Thing is, for whatever reason, it works only when I have 3 (or less) couples, meaning it works only with a max of 6 cards. Whenever I add all of the cards I created (9 couples, 18 cards) the message does not pop up
How is it possible?
App.js code is below, the  component is literally just a h1 inside a div:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SingleCard from './components/SingleCard';
import Molal from './components/Molal';

const cardImages = [
  { src: '/img/luffy.jpg', matched: false },
  { src: '/img/zoro.jpg', matched: false },
  { src: '/img/usopp.jpg', matched: false },
  /* { src: "/img/brook.jpg", matched: false }, */
  /*  { src: "/img/chopper_0.jpg", matched: false }, */
  /*  { src: "/img/franky.jpg", matched: false },  */
  /* { src: "/img/nami.jpg", matched: false }, */
  /* { src: "/img/sanji.jpg", matched: false }, */
  /*   { src: "/img/robin.jpg", matched: false },   */
];

function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);
  const [choiceOne, setChoiceOne] = useState(null);
  const [choiceTwo, setChoiceTwo] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(0);

  const shuffleCards = () => {
    const shuffledCards = [...cardImages, ...cardImages]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((card) => ({ ...card, id: Math.random() }));

    setChoiceOne(null);
    setChoiceTwo(null);
    setCards(shuffledCards);
    setTurns(0);
    setMatches(0);
  };

  /* handle choices */

  const handleChoice = (card) => {
    if (choiceOne && choiceOne.id !== card.id) {
      setChoiceTwo(card);
    } else {
      setChoiceOne(card);
    }
  };

  /*   compare cards */

  useEffect(() => {
    if (choiceOne && choiceTwo) {
      setDisabled(true);
      if (choiceOne.src === choiceTwo.src) {
        setCards((prevCards) => {
          return prevCards.map((card) => {
            if (card.src === choiceOne.src) {
              setMatches(matches + 1);
              return { ...card, matched: true };
            } else {
              return card;
            }
          });
        });
        resetTurn();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => resetTurn(), 1000);
      }
    }
  }, [choiceOne, choiceTwo, matches]);

  /*   reset & add turn */

  const resetTurn = () => {
    setChoiceOne(null);
    setChoiceTwo(null);
    setTurns((prevTurns) => prevTurns + 1);
    setMatches(0);
    setDisabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>
        <span className='animate__animated animate__bounce'> One Piece</span>{' '}
        Memory Game
      </h1>
      <button onClick={shuffleCards}>New Game</button>
      {matches === cardImages.length ? (
        <Molal />
      ) : (
        <div className='card-grid'>
          {cards.map((card) => (
            <SingleCard
              key={card.id}
              card={card}
              handleChoice={handleChoice}
              flipped={card === choiceOne || card === choiceTwo || card.matched}
              disabled={disabled}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      <p>
        Turn: <span className='red'>{turns}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Avoid calling a setter inside another setter (setMatches in setCards). Also, you call resetTurn after setCards which `setMatches(0);` which is probably a bug

Comment: also, why generate random numbers for card ids? use the iteration key instead (randomness !== uniqueness). it's probably not causing big issues, but it's something to think about :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! That was it!!!! I can't even tell why I added that setter there!! Have a nice weekend, thanks again!